# Symfony2 deployment process - windows

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, xampp

I've successfully installed NetBeans and Symfony2 and have run my first hello world locally. I've been looking around to see if there is any easy step by step way to deploy it on a server, or for my case to another directory (just to test). But I'm still not sure how that will work. I've spent way too much time on this, and I thought I'd give StackOverflow a try. I'm working on Windows, using XAMPP.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: First you should give you a try reading the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html).

Comment: im using apache and mysql, essentially running xampp .. the first project I have is in C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstProject

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into capifony:

http://capifony.org

It's based on capistrano, which is used to deploy RoR apps.

Comment: Denis, I replied to you up the below!

Answer (score 0):

Denis, in order to run "gem install capifony" I had to install Ruby2.0 then install RubyGems. So far I have the following code in "app/config/deploy.rb":

```
set :application, "set your application name here"
set :domain,      "#{application}.com"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/#{domain}"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "#{domain}:/var/repos/#{application}.git"
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Symfony2 migrations will run

set  :keep_releases,  3

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
# logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Now how can I change this to deploy my project from "C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstProject" (which contains deploy.rb) to "C:\xampp\htdocs\FirstProject1" (empty!) for example!